# Как присвоить права на VPS

Tags: vps, права

Стоит VPS на windows server, как папке присвоить права 777?

Comment: )))) спасибо, таких вопросов я еще не видел.... :))))но присвоить можно: удаляем виндов, стваим линукс, присваиваем, PROFT!!!

Answer (score 1):

Зато есть права на полный доступ.
В проводнике: Сервис > Свойства папки > вкладка "Вид" > снять галку "использовать простой общий доступ"
После этого жмем кнопу "Применить для всех папок" (здесь же).
После этого на нужной папке: по ПКМ "Свойства папки" > Доступ > Открыть общий доступ , станет активна кнопка "Разрешения", жмем, после этого и настраиваем кому какие права на папку. Вам нужен everyone (все) - ему и выставляем полный доступ.
В инете все это есть.
Можно и в консоли все это проделать, но в том и другом случае необходимы права локального админа.

Answer (score 0):

Если в `vps` крутится линукс, то нужно зайти в линукс и сделать

```
chmod -r 777 ./папка
```

Comment: нет, у меня винда, на линуксе я и сам знаю как

Comment: на виндовсе нет прав 777, если мы говорим про ntfs

Answer (score 0):

Ещё, при отсутствии прав админа, попробуйте просто переименовать папку для временных файлов (типа, `tmp` или `temp`), которая обычно имеет нужный вам уровень доступа, в нужное имя, а затем создайте заново папку для временных файлов.